# The view savedb.views.cost didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, django-views

In view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from savedb.models import Cost
from savedb.forms import CostForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
def cost(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
      form=CostForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
        date     = request.POST.get('date', '')
        cost     = request.POST.get('cost', '')
        cost_obj = Cost(date=date, cost=cost)
        cost_obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('savedb:cost'))
  else:
      form = CostForm()
      return render(request,'savedb/cost.html',{'form':form,})
```

And error is

```
The view savedb.views.cost didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

how to solve this error ...please help me ....thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Message states pretty clear, what you are doing wrong ;)

> The view savedb.views.cost didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

You probably did a `POST` with an invalid Form, right?
In your code, you only return something, when the form is valid, not if it is invalid.

Try putting a `render(request,'savedb/cost.html',{'form':form,})`  at the end of your code.
See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/) for more information.

Comment: No, in your posted code, the  `else` part handles the case, where you call a GET on the form. Try adding an `else` after your `if form.is_valid():` block on the same indentation level.

Comment: As you said i edit my code but still same  error  is occur

Answer (score 0):

The last three lines are indented too far. Move them back one level.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from savedb.models import Cost
from savedb.forms import CostForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect , HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse

def cost(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form1=CostForm(request.POST)
       if form1.is_valid(): 
         date     = request.POST.get('date', '')
         cost     = request.POST.get('cost', '')
         cost_obj = Cost(date=date, cost=cost)
         cost_obj.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('savedb:cost'))

    else:
          form = CostForm()
          return render(request,'savedb/cost.html',{'form1':form,})
```

Thanks all! 
I am done with it. Just import necessary model